# node.js sqlite select all rows not working

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

in my routes folder I need a query to select every row from a table. Or I need the number of rows. Therefore I used this code:

```
 let sql4 = 'SELECT * FROM Beitrag';
        db.get(sql4, (err, allRows)=>{
            if(err){console.log(err)}
            
            console.log(allRows);
        });
```

But I only get the first row. Does anyone know why ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = "your database conection";

    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query("SELECT * FROM Beitrag", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Does not change anything. I got only the first row

Answer (score 0):

Got it. db.get only returns the first row. Use db.all to get all the rows.